# Finding the file path (server directory) from using Firebug

Tags: css, magento, directory, filepath

I am a super beginner and am learning as I go, so please be patient with me!

So here goes:

I am trying to make some edits on a Magento theme (removing buttons - Twitter, to be exact) and am using FireBug (Firefox Add-On) to locate the directory to remove the button.

Firebug will allow me to find the CSS directory in order to change certain things but does not show the file to make edits in to remove the button.  From other similar questions, I have gathered that it is not possible to find server directory paths from apps like Firebug (or is it?); however, is there any advice or easier method to go about finding the location of the button?

Any information helps, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you cannot use firebug to find in which file that button is inserted. You have to go to magento admin, `system- > configuration -> developer`. Select your website in view top left. then in `template path hints` select yes. Now go into frontend and refresh. You will see a lot of red lines with the path to the folders where everything is. Do not do this in production as it is a negative experience for customers.

Comment: awesome advice. i was able to locate the file.  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try saving the file locally by doing ctrl + s. That may give you the css file to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this step by step instruction:

```
Step 1: System >> Configuration >> Developer
```

your current configuration scope is set to “Default Config.” You cannot setup Magento Template Path Hints globally. You’ll need to set the Configuration Scope to a website or store configuration. When you do, you’ll see a screen like this:

[image]

Change Template Path Hints no to yes and save the configuration. Reload your front page.

For more [info](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-in.html)